# How does one identify a Black Sky?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015, the-defenders-2017

We know that

> Elektra is a Black Sky.

We also know that there are other Black Sky, such as the child that we saw on *Daredevil*.  Various actors, such as Stick and the Hand, seem to know that the aforementioned individual is a Black Sky, and certainly the Hand was able to find other Black Sky.

How do they know that someone is a Black Sky? There don’t seem to be any really obvious signs.

Comment: It seems that Elektra's propensity to violence had been a factor in her identification as a Black Sky by Stick's Chaste fellow.